# Dual citizen traveling to Canada and US

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, dual-nationality, event-based-effects

I am Canadian and US citizen but born in Iran. Every week, I go to Canada to visit a friend and return to US without any issue, my question is: due to the new rule can I go to Canada to visit my friend and return without having any issue at the US border?

Is my passport/Nexus card going to be taken away from me?

Comment: What new rule are you talking about?

Comment: I suspect that your question is related to the recent reports of [US citizens of Iranian origin being detained at the US border](https://www.npr.org/2020/01/07/794266317/border-screenings-spark-travel-fears-for-iranian-americans-amid-rising-tensions) — is that correct?

Comment: As you a US citizen, they can't refuse you entry even if you show up naked, covered in slime and mumbling "They're heeeeeere". That's what citizenship means.  The only conceivable risk I see is that for a *naturalized* citizen, certain very outrageous behaviors can cause such a citizenship to be revoked

Comment: If you're a US citizen traveling to the US, you should use your US passport. In the US, as long as you have a US passport with you, there's not that much to worry about at border control.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica as far as I'm aware, denaturalization can happen only when there has been fraud in the immigration process, which typically involves "certain outrageous behaviors" *before* naturalization (or other grounds of inadmissibility) that were concealed from US authorities despite being material to some application or another. Other loss of nationality requires consent. Your comment implies that some outrageous acts after naturalization could result in loss of US nationality without consent. Was that intended, and, if so, what acts did you have in mind?

Comment: @phoog typically, yes, but that's not relevant to OP.  I almost added a sentence on this.  I mean outrageous acts whose nature, and supporting facts, make it apparent that the original citizenship application was a sham all along. Say you have an import-export business, and then they find 23 workers being snuck in on one of your truckloads of goods, and in the full view of things, it's apparent you are the "inside man" on the US side of trafficking ring that you were part of all along.

Comment: You should really add the rule to "due to the new rule" to the question.

Comment: @phoog That's not totally correct. INA 340(a) provides for denaturalization based on refusal to testify before a congressional committee during the 10 years after naturalization. INA 340(c) provides for denaturalization based on joining a communist, totalitarian, or anarchist organization during the 5 years after naturalization.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica but the "all along" part of "part of all along" implies that a material fact was withheld from an application at some point before naturalization, so that's not a different basis for denaturalization.

Comment: @Brian thanks for pointing those out. I note that subsection (a) doesn't apply to *all* refusals but only to those that concern the person's own subversive activities. Furthermore, (c) provides that joining certain groups is not grounds for denaturalization but prima facie evidence of the person's state of mind (rebuttable with "countervailing evidence") showing "concealment of a material fact" or "willful misrepresentation." It's effectively another way of demonstrating a fraudulent application. I wonder if these would survive (or have survived) challenges under the 1st or 5th amendments.

Comment: @phoog I meant outrageous behaviors *after* citizenship. For instance you might have associations with traffickers in Mexico, and those alone would not disqualify your citizenship. But then *after* becoming a citizen, you immediately become the US-side "mule" for their trafficking operation. This now makes it clear that your real motivation for citizenship was to allow you to commit crime as a citizen. The criminal activity afterwards is what makes the citizenship fraudulent. If you'd quit the syndicate and gone to Seattle to build Dreamliners, that would legitimize it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica that makes more sense.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Does your passport or NEXUS card state that you were born in Iran?

Comment: @phoog IMHO, saying "if you do this thing after you get citizenship, it's evidence that you weren't eligible for it in the first place" is an end-run around the 14th amendment and the precedent in *Afroyim v. Rusk*. If it were held constitutional, then there would be nothing stopping Congress from passing some law saying that basically *any* act that demonstrates lack of good moral character *after* naturalization would be prima facie evidence of ineligibility at the time of naturalization ... (1/2)

Comment: @phoog ... The citizen would then be placed in the impossible situation of arguing "actually, I was a good person at the time when my citizenship was granted, I only became a bad person afterward" or else losing their citizenship. Such absurdities would seem to be the logical outcome of upholding this kind of congressional sophistry. (2/2)

Comment: @Brian the whole denaturalization-because-of-deception shtick could be seen as an end run around *Afroyim,* but I suspect that that argument has already been tested unsuccessfully.  Whether anyone has ever been denaturalized under 340(c) (and, if so, whether they've challenged it with an argument like the one you've outlined) would be interesting to know.

Comment: @phoog I looked into it, and I found an article in a law review that claimed that no one has ever been denaturalized under 340(c). It also laid out several arguments for why the law should be considered unconstitutional, without mentioning any direct challenge to it. Finally, I searched Google Scholar and found plenty of references to 340(a) but none to 340(c). So, I don't think its constitutionality has been tested.

Comment: @Brian thanks for that.  You might post a question and self-answer at [Law.SE] to preserve the fruits of your labor (comments are not searchable and are more likely to be deleted).

Answer (score 19):

Your passport cannot be taken from you because you were born in Iran.  You cannot be deprived of US citizenship because you were born in Iran.  As a US citizen, you cannot be refused entry to the US.  None of that changes because you hold another citizenship in addition to the US citizenship.

However, we can't predict whether you'll be temporarily detained for any reason, as some US citizens with Iranian backgrounds recently have been, nor how long you might be delayed at the border.  As far as I've heard, those reports were limited to one port of entry in Washington state, but I have not followed it closely.

You might want to see if the local chapter of the American Civil Liberties Union can give you the number of a lawyer to call in case there is a problem.  If you do make the trip, please come back and post an answer describing your experience.

Comment: Note this answer relies very heavily on border agents following the law and the Geneva convention. Which you would think is a given but *shrug* these days I just don't know.

Comment: @corsiKa which Geneva convention?  Whatever one you're thinking of, I doubt it has direct force of law in the US.  What violation of the law do you imagine CBP immigration officers might commit?  What would they do that would prevent a US citizen with a valid US passport from entering the US?  If they have reason to question the legitimacy of the citizenship (or of the document), which isn't illegal on its face, they can do that, of course, but a person's Iranian background is not reason to question the legitimacy of the person's citizenship or passport.

Comment: Geneva has become synonymous with "basic human rights" in modern vernacular. Your claim of "a person's Iranian background is not reason to question the legitimacy of the person's citizenship or passport" flies directly in the face of the experience of a number of my friends from the Middle East. If an agent was to deny entry to a US passport holder, which would be illegal, they would be unlikely to face any consequences.

Comment: @corsiKa the problem with using "Geneva conventions" as a loose synonym for "basic human rights" is that there are some Geneva conventions that do have the force of law in the US, so it's imprecise and confusing.  How many of your friends from the middle east have been accused or apparently suspected of falsely claiming US citizenship?  How many were refused entry in the US?  An agent refusing entry to a US citizen without a legitimate doubt as to the person's citizenship would not likely be protected by qualified immunity, so liable for civil damages, and/or the US would be liable under FTCA.